How to share iPad's internet to Ubuntu 24.04 running on Orange Pi?
I want to use an iPad Pro as a device that connect to the Orange PI via USB-C or Ad-Hoc Wireless.
The Orange PI will be running Visual Studio Code Server.
The internet should be shared from the iPad (Personal Hotspot OR Tethered via USB-C)
Can anyone please help me with getting this to work?
Ubuntu on ARM (Rockchip)
Ubuntu 24 LTS is the OS

Does iPad have an option to set up a Wifi hotspot or (reverse) USB tethering? If so, just do it from the iPad and connect to internet on the Orange Pi in the regular way. This seems to be an iPad question rather than a Ubuntu question.

Here is how to use iPad as a personal hotspot device https://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-turn-your-ipad-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot-in-easy-steps/
